# Give control of terminal to server contacted via HTTP

Tags: terminal, fifo

I have an application that runs an HTTP server. The application also has a command-line interface. The app is written in Ruby and the startup time is significant. Using the command-line interface is fairly slow for this reason.

```
# this is slow
$ my-app do something
```

I often run an instance of the HTTP server locally. I have written an endpoint for the server that is a kind of shunt for the CLI. It takes a series of arguments (like ARGV on the command line), and executes the corresponding CLI command in the server process.

```
# this is faster since the command is executed in the already-running process
$ curl http://my.app/cli?argv=do&argv=something
```

I would like to use this endpoint rather than the CLI when the server is running. Here is my issue: some of my CLI commands are interactive. When I make a request to the server, `curl` gets read/write access to the terminal, not the server process. Is there a way to give the server temporary access to the terminal, so that I can run an interactive command with an http request just as if it had been launched directly from the command line? One possibility would be to open up a named pipe on the server and return the path from the HTTP request. But then how would I "connect" the terminal to this?

```
# this lets me interact with the command
$ my-app do something

# this does not
$ curl http://my.app/cli?argv=do&argv=something
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by passing the path to the terminal device file over http. You can get this path with: `tty`

```
$ curl http://my.app/cli?argv=do&argv=something&tty=$(tty)
```

Then it is simply a matter of opening the passed tty file on the server and reading/writing to it instead of STDIN/STDOUT.